# SQL Query of Excel Spreadsheet Connection Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a sql query against my Excel workbook but I can not get the connection to open.  It fails on the cn.Open strCon line with a Unspecified error Runtime error '-2147467259(80004005)'.

```
Function Test()

Dim cn As Object 'ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
Dim currAddress As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCon As String

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM AdelPivot"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sql = rs.GetString

End Function
```

Comment: What version of Excel is the file in? Also, when you get it working, dont forget to close rs and cn and set them to nothing.

Comment: Excel 2010. Thanks for the tip on closing connections.

Comment: This line shouldn't compile: `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ["Data"]"` Has your workbook been saved?

Comment: The variable `Sql` isn't declared anywhere. In Excel, it's more usual to do something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` to output the recordset data